# How to rotate my 3D plots by mouse in PyCharm professional?

Tags: python, matplotlib, pycharm

I am new to python and matplotlib. I worked on them by PyCharm Community Version for several months. In it, I do some plottings like below:

```
from mpl_toolkits import mplot3d
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
fig = plt.figure(figsize=[16, 8])
ax = fig.add_subplot(1, 2, 1, projection='3d')
ax.scatter3D(x, y, z, s=10, c='g')
plt.show()
```

Then I get a 3D plot in which I can use my mouse to drag it to rotate it.

I tried the professional version of PyCharm recently, and I do the same thing. I got the plot in a "SciView" window. And I cannot drag it at all, like the screenshot below:

[image]

I seek solutions in google and turned the Scientific mode off by menu View - Scientific Mode, but It is still as it was.

Kindly could anyone familiar with it guide me?

( Some links to the knowledge of PyCharm and matplotlib related to this problem are also appreciated. )

Answer (score 6):

I finally find the solution:
Tick off the switch in menu
Settings/Preferences | Tools | Python Scientific
from https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/matplotlib-support.html#console

But I still do not know the knowledge under the hood.

Comment: They didnt fix this from 2017
https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/115000742910-SciView-3d-plots-not-draggable-rotationable